# How can I convert a diagram to Java code?

Tags: java, class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I have a figure need to convert to Java code..

This is the figure:
[image: figure]

Is this Java code correct?

```
class Insurance_company {
    private ArrayList<contract> Insurance_contract;
}

class Insurance_contract {
    private Insurance_company company;
}
```

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this code apart from names. `InsuranceCompany` is associated with `0` or more `InsuranceContract`. And `InsuranceContract` is associated  with `1` `InsuranceCompany`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `contract` class, so that Arraylist type is incorrect.

The company has zero-to-many contracts.

```
class Insurance_company {
    private List<Insurance_contract> contracts;
}
```

Your `Insurance_contract` seems correct.